# "No matching pods found" in GKE Logs

Tags: logging, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam

`Logs explorer` is showing the below logs for `GKE`

```
  2020-12-30 21:46:58.000 IST  "No matching pods found"
  2020-12-30 21:41:58.000 IST  "No matching pods found"
```

Is it because of any missing `IAM Role` , the cluster logs are not available in `Logs Explorer` ?

Comment: Please provide further information to better address this issue or determine what is causing this behavior such as: whether the cluster (master or nodes) has been recently upgraded, when the issue started.

Also, please check if metric-server and gke-metrics-agent pods are running `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

Comment: Could you please try to add the roles/logging.logWriter (Logs Writer Role) to your GKE service account? This could be happening due to insufficient permissions as you mentioned. More information can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control)

Comment: Yeah..that was the issue actually...the permission was missing